# Join statement in ruby on rails throws up error MySQL::Error: Unknown column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
parts = Participation.joins(:booking).where(bookings: { date_of_booking: Date.yesterday }, payment_status: 2)
```

I have the above join statement, even though the column `date_of_booking` exists, mysql throws up error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'bookings.date_of_booking' in 'where clause': SELECT `ad_trek_participant`.* FROM `ad_trek_participant` INNER JOIN `ad_trek_booking` ON `ad_trek_booking`.`Id` = `ad_trek_participant`.`Booking_Id` WHERE `bookings`.`date_of_booking` = '2017-02-13' AND `ad_trek_participant`.`payment_status` = 2

Any help on this please.

Comment: What is the association between `Participation` and `Booking`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale The `Participation belongs_to Booking` and `Booking has_many Participatipation`

Comment: Can you please post the table structure of both models

Comment: I believe your table name is ad_trek_bookings from the error.  Not bookings. Try that name in your where?  Looks like you are using diff table name from convention and masking it, then rails is getting confused in this query

Comment: @dstull Thank you, I changed to `parts = Participation.joins(:booking).where(ad_trek_booking: {date_of_booking: Date.yesterday})` and it worked

Comment: @DeepakMahakale, Hey Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Participation.joins(:booking).where(payment_status: 2).where("ad_trek_booking.date_of_booking > ?",Date.today - 6.days)
```

The table name changed to `ad_trek_booking` inside `where` and `joins(:booking)` given the model name, it worked.